# How to fix my m..n relationship in nosql (mongodb)?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

At first I'm trying to make a rally (you know cars with drivers...) database. I have two collections: `drivers { name, address, sex, ... }` and then another one `tournaments { name, location, price, ... }`

I try to keep it simple. In a tournament there should be drivers (because a tournament without drivers...well its not nice ^^). And there is my problem, in a normal sql database I could select two primary keys (lets say name in drivers and name in tournaments - just to keep it simple, I know name as primary key is not nice). And because its an m..n relationship (is it right?) I would make a 3. Table with the two primary keys. OK that would be easy. But how should I solve this problem in mongodb. I thought something like: `tournaments { name, location, price, ... drivers { driver_1, ..., driver_n } }` , but im not sure. I'm using Java so I could make some special Classes which one is handling this relationship problem? I don't understand the other mongodb tutorials. Any ideas? Thank you for any help!

Comment: How can something be tagged both `sql` and `nosql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. As @Gianluca describes you can perform this linking manually by adding a driver's `_id` ObjectId or another identifying property (probably one you have a unique index on) to a "drivers" array in a tournament document. e.g. tournament : `{ ... drivers : ["6019235867192384", "73510945093", ...]}`
2. Another option specifically built for this referencing is the `DBRef` specification which provides a more formal method probably more similar to what you're familiar in the SQL world. DBRef is supported by the java driver and allows you to scope your reference to a collection (basically saying where this reference comes from). I wouldn't be surprised if in the future versions of MongoDB cross-collection queries will be supported, although they are not currently.

More information [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef).

Also if you aren't using a DAO framework I would suggest [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) which supports DBRef with a nice `@Reference` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using the _id field that every document had and is unique.

So in you case you just need to create a collection that has the ObjectId of the torunaments and some ObjectId from the collection drivers. Or you can just put the ObejctId of the driver directly in the torunaments collection. Probably not the best solution, but it work

Gianluca

Answer (score 2):

Add an array field `drivers` in the `trournaments` type and put the `_id`s of the drivers in there.

To add/remove drivers, just update the field. There is no need for an intermediary N:M mapping table unless the array gets really huge.

If it gets huge, the usual solution is to cut the array into several smaller ones and save them in several documents that you can look up quickly by using the `id_` of the container (the tournament). Removing and sorting is then a pain, of course.